# HD-SDI monitor locks-unlocks

Tags: fpga, pll

I have an SD/HD/3G-SDI output driven by a LMH0303, pretty much stock standard application circuit straight out of the datasheet.
The SDI datastream is generated by an XC7K70T FPGA, so I have great control over pixel clock frequency and video data.
When connected to a Sony Trimaster EL SDI monitor, the output video is stable and flawless. When connected to a Macro Blue SDI monitor, the display is on for 10-15 seconds, then loses signal, re-locks after a few seconds and so on.
PLLs inside the FPGA are locked, and the 74.25 MHz reference clock for 1080p30 is coming from a precision, low-jitter source (Si5324), in which the PLL is also locked. 
Any ideas what else, other than jitter, can cause this behavior?

Comment: Kind of a silly question, but can you make sure that the clock used for the transceivers is the precision clock, I had a few designs (from Xilinx example designs) that had the problem of mixing clock sources on the transceiver module connection.

Comment: Yes, it is the precision clock. In fact, my design has two clock sources, a ASEMPLV-148.500MHZ low-jitter oscillator, and a Si5324 precision PLL. When the oscillator is used as the CPLL driver, and data is generated by a colorbar generator inside the FPGA, I still see the issue. Another clue since I posted the original question: When the equalizer on the RX side is physically (short wires on the PCB) looped back to drive the Tx side line driver (LMH0303), so the FPGA is disconnected, the device on the Rx side drives the Tx side as if I had a repeater, the monitor attached to the TX side locks.